# Does SARSA(0) converge to the optimal policy in expectation if the Robbins-Monro conditions are removed?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, proofs, convergence, temporal-difference-methods

The conditions of convergence of SARSA(0) to the optimal policy are :

1. The Robbins-Monro conditions above hold for $α_t$.
2. Every state-action pair is visited infinitely often
3. The policy is greedy with respect to the policy derived from $Q$ in the limit
4. The controlled Markov chain is communicating: every state can be reached from any other with positive probability (under some policy).
5. $\operatorname{Var}{R(s, a)} < \infty$, where $R$ is the reward function

The original proof of the convergence of TD(0) prediction (page 24 of the paper [Learning to Predict by the Method of Temporal Differences](http://incompleteideas.net/papers/sutton-88-with-erratum.pdf)) was for convergence in the mean of the estimation to the true value function. This did not require the learning rate parameter to satisfy Robbins-Monro conditions.

I was wondering if the Robbins-Monro conditions are removed from the SARSA(0) assumptions would the policy converge in some notion of expectation to the optimal policy?